# Sum hash elements with Perl

Tags: perl, hash, sum

I have a Perl script that returns this hash structure :

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Week' => [
                      '1238',
                      {
                        'OUT3FA_5' => 65,
                        'OUT3A_5' => 20,
                        'OUT3-Fix' => 45,
                        'IN1' => 85
                      },
                      '1226',
                      {
                        'OUT3FA_5' => 30,
                        'OUT3A_5' => 5,
                        'OUT3-Fix' => 25,
                        'IN1' => 40
                      }
                    ]
        };
```

What I'd like to do is, count the total of `IN1` for each week, per example in this case it'll return:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Week' => [
                      '1238',
                      {
                        'OUT3FA_5' => 65,
                        'Total_IN1' => 85,
                        'OUT3A_5' => 20,
                        'OUT3-Fix' => 45,
                        'IN1' => 85
                      },
                      '1226',
                      {
                        'OUT3FA_5' => 30,
                        'Total_IN1' => 125,
                        'OUT3A_5' => 5,
                        'OUT3-Fix' => 25,
                        'IN1' => 40
                      }
                    ]
        };
```

And so on for each week.

How can I do this please? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I tried to do but it's not working :

```
my @sum_IN1 = qw(IN1); #kinda useless to use an array just for one value...
for my $num (keys %hash) {

    my $found;
    my $sum = 0;

    for my $key (@sum_IN1) {

        next unless exists $hash{$num}{$key};
        $sum   += $hash{$num}{$key};
        $found = 1;
    }

    $hash{$num}{Total_IN1} = $sum if $found;
}
```

Comment: why you sum IN1 in (week 1238 and week 1226) and save sum in week 1226?

Comment: oups yes sorry my mistake, the weeks should be sorted, week 1238 and week 1239. The last week (1239) is where I should sum IN1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a state variable holding the running total for each item in the array. I also suspect that you `Week` array is supposed to be a hash?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my $data = {
  Week => [
    1238,
    { "IN1" => 85, "OUT3-Fix" => 45, "OUT3A_5" => 20, "OUT3FA_5" => 65 },
    1226,
    { "IN1" => 40, "OUT3-Fix" => 25, "OUT3A_5" => 5, "OUT3FA_5" => 30 },
  ],
};

my $week = $data->{Week};

# Sort the array entry pairs by week number
#
my @pairs;
push @pairs, [ splice @$week, 0, 2 ] while @$week;
@$week = ();
for my $pair (sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @pairs) {
  push @$week, @$pair;
}

# Calculate the running totals of IN1
#
my $total = 0;
for my $item (@$week) {
  next unless ref $item eq 'HASH' and exists $item->{IN1};
  $total += $item->{IN1};
  $item->{Total_IN1} = $total;
}

dd $data;
```

**output**

```
{
  Week => [
    1226,
    {
      "IN1"       => 40,
      "OUT3-Fix"  => 25,
      "OUT3A_5"   => 5,
      "OUT3FA_5"  => 30,
      "Total_IN1" => 40,
    },
    1238,
    {
      "IN1"       => 85,
      "OUT3-Fix"  => 45,
      "OUT3A_5"   => 20,
      "OUT3FA_5"  => 65,
      "Total_IN1" => 125,
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me and I also find it simple to understand and to use. Can I ask you just one more question, I'd like to sort my weeks before doing the sum, in this case `1238` will have the `"Total_IN1" => 125`, how can I do this?

Comment: It would make this a *lot* easier if you kept your week data as a hash instead of as an array. It was like this in your previous questions, and I wonder if the change to an array is accidental or deliberate? Sorting the data as it stands is possible but not straightforward, and I have added a block to my solution to show how to do it. But please revert to a hash if you possible can.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I had other Weeks? 1226 1238 1227 1239 with your method it'll return `1239 1227 1238 1226` and it's not what I need, I need to sort them numerically.

Comment: The change I have made to the code sorts the data by week number, as the output shows. I'm just saying it would be a lot more straightforward if you hadn't changed to using an array.

Answer (score 2):

First, your data structure is confusing. `'Week'` is a reference to an array, some of whose elements are strings (such as `'1238'`) and the rest of whose elements are hash references.

While Perl lets you get away with this, it would be a better design for each level of your data structure to hold only one kind of thing.  This is something to consider.  However, I will leave it as is for now.

Here is a quick way to do it:

```
my $ttl = 0;
$_->{'In1Total'} = $ttl+=$_->{'IN1'} || 0 for(grep {ref $_} @{$VAR1->{'Week'}});

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $VAR1;
```

**Update:** changed `//` to `||` as Mikko L suggested.

Explanation:

`grep {ref $_}` gets only the elements that are hash references out of the array.

`$_->{'IN1'} || 0` - If one of the hashes did not have `'IN1'`, this would use zero instead. This is basically a check for the hash key being defined.  `||` is acceptable to do this for hash keys.  In other situations, however, you need the defined-or operator (`//`, available from version 5.10 I believe).

`$_->{'In1Total'} = $total+=$_->{'IN1'} || 0` this adds the current value of `IN1` to the count, then puts the result into `In1Total`.  Admittedly this could be made a bit clearer by separating it into a couple of lines.

**Update 2:** fixed mistake Borodin pointed out.

Comment: Nice, concise, functional, I like it. Can be difficult to read for less experienced, however. Also, if stuck on an ancient version of perl, I think you could use `||` in place of `//` in this case.

Comment: @MikkoL, thanks for your helpful comments.  I have made the change you suggested, as well as added some explanation.  I wanted to show that the code could be made a lot simpler, but perhaps I was overzealous in reducing it down.

Comment: The functional approach is excellent in many ways and definitely worth learning, not to mention elegant (IMHO). Your code with the added explanation is a great resource to get started! Thank you for contributing!

Comment: This code won't run under `use strict` and `use warnings`, so I suggest using `grep ref, @{$VAR1->{Week}}` instead. Also there is little point in using `||` over `//` when what you really mean is `exists $_->{IN1} ? $_->{'IN1'} : 0`. I believe `//` is preferable.

Comment: @Borodin, thanks for pointing that out. Whoops! Commenting out `use strict;` while testing something then forgetting to put it back in = a bad idea. As for `//` vs. `||`, they work the same in this case and neither one produces a warning on a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: Concise and functional, yes, but a bit overkill for a newbie. For the sake of readability (and understandability), fully written-out loops are better.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to see why it is not working, but it may be because you are using a hash in your code, but the data structure returned is a hash reference.

Here is a version which should work (using hash references):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );

my $data = {
    'Week' => [
        '1238',
        {   'IN1'      => 85,
            'OUT3FA_5' => 65,
            'OUT3A_5'  => 20,
            'OUT3-Fix' => 45
        },
        '1226',
        {   'IN1'      => 40,
            'OUT3FA_5' => 30,
            'OUT3A_5'  => 5,
            'OUT3-Fix' => 25
        }
    ]
};

for my $key ( keys %$data ) {
    my $weekly_data = $data->{$key};
    my $total       = 0;
    my $iter        = natatime 2, @$weekly_data;

    while ( my ( $id, $daily_data ) = $iter->() ) {
        next unless $daily_data->{IN1};
        $total += $daily_data->{IN1};
        $daily_data->{Total_IN1} = $total;
    }
}

print Dumper($data);
1;
```

Here's the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Week' => [
                      '1238',
                      {
                        'OUT3FA_5' => 65,
                        'Total_IN1' => 85,
                        'OUT3A_5' => 20,
                        'OUT3-Fix' => 45,
                        'IN1' => 85
                      },
                      '1226',
                      {
                        'OUT3FA_5' => 30,
                        'Total_IN1' => 125,
                        'OUT3A_5' => 5,
                        'OUT3-Fix' => 25,
                        'IN1' => 40
                      }
                    ]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could learn something from a modification of your code, which, btw, works perfectly. The problem is that you treat the data structure wrong. This:

```
# initial data structure
my $data = {
    'Week' => [
        '1238',
        {
            'IN1' => 85,
            'OUT3FA_5' => 65,
            'OUT3A_5' => 20,
            'OUT3-Fix' => 45
        },
        '1226',
        {                        
            'IN1' => 40,
            'OUT3FA_5' => 30,                       
            'OUT3A_5' => 5,
            'OUT3-Fix' => 25
        },
    ],
};
```

Is a hash reference. In the referenced hash, there's a key `Week` that points to an array reference of key-value pairs. So this should be a hash instead:

```
# create a Week hash from the even-sized list in $data->{Week}
my %week = @{$data->{Week}};
```

The I just needed to replace some variable names in your code:

```
my @sum_IN1 = qw(IN1);
for my $num (keys %week) {

    my $found;
    my $sum = 0;

    for my $key (@sum_IN1) {

        next unless exists $week{$num}{$key};
        $sum   += $week{$num}{$key};
        $found = 1;
    }

    $week{$num}{Total_IN1} = $sum if $found;
}

print Dumper \%week;
```

That works fine! Output (in wrong order, but you can `sort` it easily):

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1238' => {
                      'OUT3FA_5' => 65,
                      'Total_IN1' => 85,
                      'OUT3A_5' => 20,
                      'OUT3-Fix' => 45,
                      'IN1' => 85
                    },
          '1226' => {
                      'OUT3FA_5' => 30,
                      'Total_IN1' => 40,
                      'OUT3A_5' => 5,
                      'OUT3-Fix' => 25,
                      'IN1' => 40
                    }
        };
```

Comment: Come on, why the downvote? I didn't use bad practices, I helped the OP to improve his solution instead of rewriting it completely and I tested my code with the right result. At least leave a comment.